# please fix following multithreading code in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

```
  import time from threading
  import thread

  def myfunc(i):  #Each thread runs this function
    print "sleep from thread %d" % i
    time. Sleep(5)
    print "woke up from thread %d" % i
    return

  for i in range(10): # Create 10 Thread objects
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i,))
    t.start() #Start Each Thread
    return
```

it throws following error .

> File "threading.py", line 1
>       import time from threading
>                      ^   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If you're trying to import something called "time" from something called "threading", the syntax is `from threading import time`.

Comment: D:\practice_exercise>python threading.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1, in <module>
    from threading import time
  File "D:\practice_exercise\threading.py", line 1, in <module>
    from threading import time
ImportError: cannot import name time

Comment: That means you're trying to import something that doesn't exist. There's nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

For the error you are pointing out, this is because the import statement should be like so :
`from threading import time`